# Computing features over the same dataframe

Tags: r

The following code computes three different features over the same dataset. I'm not sure if the `filter_by_day_segment` function can be made tidy or there's a more efficient/short but still readable way of refactor my code.

```
library(dplyr)

filter_by_day_segment <- function(data, day_segment){
  if(day_segment == "daily"){
    return(data %>% group_by(local_date))
  } else {
    return(data %>% filter(day_segment == local_day_segment) %>% group_by(local_date))
  } 
}
compute_metric <- function(data, metric, day_segment){
  if(metric == "countscans"){
    data <- filter_by_day_segment(data, day_segment)
    return(data %>% summarise(!!paste("sensor", day_segment, metric, sep = "_") := n()))
  }else if(metric == "uniquedevices"){
    data <- filter_by_day_segment(data, day_segment)
    return(data %>% summarise(!!paste("sensor", day_segment, metric, sep = "_") := n_distinct(value)))
  }
  else if(metric == "countscansmostuniquedevice"){
    data <- data %>% group_by(value) %>% 
      mutate(N=n()) %>% 
      ungroup() %>%
      filter(N == max(N))
    data <- filter_by_day_segment(data, day_segment)
    return(data %>% summarise(!!paste("sensor", day_segment, metric, sep = "_") := n()))
  }

}

data <- read.csv("test.csv")


day_segment <- "daily"
metrics <-  c("countscans", "uniquedevices", "countscansmostuniquedevice")

features = data.frame()
for(metric in metrics){
  feature <- compute_metric(data, metric, day_segment)
  if(nrow(features) == 0){
    features <- feature
  } else{
    features <- merge(features, feature, by="local_date", all = TRUE)
  }
}

print(features)
```

A test CSV file

```
"local_date","value"
"2018-05-21","FC:44"
"2018-05-21","FC:58"
"2018-05-21","FF:7E"
"2018-05-21","F8:77"
"2018-05-21","F8:77"
"2018-05-22","FB:F1"
"2018-05-22","FC:62"
"2018-05-22","FE:D4"
"2018-05-22","FE:D4"
"2018-05-22","FC:F1"
"2018-05-23","F8:77"
"2018-05-23","F8:77"
"2018-05-23","FF:13"
"2018-05-23","F8:3F"
"2018-05-23","F8:3F"
"2018-05-23","F8:3F"
"2018-05-23","FC:B6"
"2018-05-24","FC:0D"
"2018-05-24","F8:3F"
"2018-05-24","F7:B6"
"2018-05-24","F6:96"
"2018-05-24","F6:96"
"2018-05-24","F6:96"
"2018-05-24","F6:96"
"2018-05-24","F6:96"
"2018-05-24","F6:96"
"2018-05-24","F6:96"
"2018-05-25","FC:A8"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-25","FC:44"
"2018-05-26","FC:F1"
"2018-05-26","FC:A8"
"2018-05-26","FF:89"
"2018-05-26","FF:89"
"2018-05-26","FF:89"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was reviewing this code professionally, my first comment would be that you should stick to a style guide. This will govern things like spacing between statements, brackets, operators etc. It can be seen as a kind of nitpicky remark (I certainly did at first) but having a consistent style massively aids readability for you and for others.

The second (style) comment would be that your code is halfway between very pipe-based code and "standard" R style (lots of assignment). This makes it difficult to read. If you're going to go with pipes, stick with it.

Also, when using an ifelse with more than 2 conditions, it's often clearer to use a switch block. This reduces the potential for massive nested ifs, and should also discourage you from doing much branching within the if.

I don't really like how similar the summarise calls are in each case. Ideally I would refactor that, but I think that is somewhat tricky due to how dplyr handles `n` and `n_distinct`.

This is how I would rewrite your code, though I would also consult [the tidyverse style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/) to see their recommendations -- I generally try to avoid programming with dplyr so I'm not that familiar with the style.

```r
filter_by_day_segment_refactor <- function(data, day_segment) {
  ## Minimise the amount done within the if/else clause (also reduces duplication)
  if (day_segment == "daily") {
    fun <- identity 
  } else {
    fun <- function(x) filter(x, day_segment == local_day_segment)
  }
  data %>% fun() %>% group_by(local_date)
}

compute_metric_refactor <- function(data, metric, day_segment) {
  ## 3 case switch block with just 1 pipe each, 
  ## rather than 3 conditionals with a mix of
  ## pipes and assignment
  switch(metric, 
    "countscans" = {
      data %>% 
        filter_by_day_segment(day_segment) %>%
        summarise(!!paste("sensor", day_segment, metric, sep = "_") := n())
    },
    "uniquedevices" = {
      data %>%
        filter_by_day_segment(day_segment) %>%
        summarise(!!paste("sensor", day_segment, metric, sep = "_") := n_distinct(value))
    },
    "countscansmostuniquedevice" = {
      data %>% group_by(value) %>% 
        mutate(N = n()) %>% 
        ungroup() %>%
        filter(N == max(N)) %>%
        filter_by_day_segment(day_segment) %>%
        summarise(!!paste("sensor", day_segment, metric, sep = "_") := n())
    }
  )
}
```